# In App Billling OutOfBoundException

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Hey I've a problem if I want to start the BillingFlow for my inAppPurchase it throws a exception: ArrayOutOfBound. At line 6 it is thrown but this list couldn't be null because i have set before a param of this list. So anybody knows why this exception is thrown by calling " skuDetailsList.get(0)" ?

```
List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<> ();
        skuList.add("premium_upgrade");
        SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
        params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
        mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(),(responseCode,skuDetailsList) -> {
            SkuDetails skuDetails = skuDetailsList.get(0);
            String sku = skuDetails.getSku();
            BillingFlowParams.Builder builder = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder().setSku(sku).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
            mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(this,builder.build());
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayOutOfBoundException` says that the you are trying to access a data which is out of range of the array. Since, you are getting and exeception at line `skuDetailsList.get(0)` says that the there is no data at position 0 in the list `skuDetailsList`

Please try to debug you code and check if you are getting appropriate result in `skuDetailsList`